# SELECT INTO the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a requirement where I want to rename a column. In in this case, it should happen like:

1.) I need to create a new column with the existing column structure.
2.) Migrate the data to the new column.
3.) Retain the old column.

I don't have the new column structure and I have to take it from the old column.

TIA.

Comment: Are you sure you mean retain the old columns and not remove?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'I need to create a new **table** with the existing column structure'?

Comment: I need to retain the old column. Otherwise its straightforward.

Comment: @blog: If you retain the old column your database is no longer in normal form.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to select into the same table. Perform the following steps:

1. Create the new column as nullable.
2. Use an update statement to fill the data into the new column based on the values from the old column.
3. Add a non-nullable constraint, if appropriate.
4. Update all queries and code to use the values in the new column instead of the old column.
5. Remove the old column.

Comment: This is definitely the way I would go.

Comment: 4.) How do I add the old column structure and constraints to the new one?

Comment: @blog: The way I suggest doing it, you don't need a new table, so you don't need to anything apart from the steps I've described above.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Oracle?  You can rename the column since 9i R2:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
RENAME COLUMN old_name to new_name;
```

If you're set on recreating the table so you can use `SELECT INTO`, then you'd want to use the following steps:

1. Drop constraints related to the table(s)
2. Drop indexes related to the table(s)
3. Lock the original table:

   ```
   LOCK TABLE old_table IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
   ```
4. Rename the table:

   ```
   RENAME old_table TO old_table_orig
   ```
5. Create the new table with the correct/updated columns
6. Run your `SELECT INTO` script(s) to populate the new table, handling data type changes if there are any
7. Add indexes
8. Add constraints
9. Drop the old_table_orig

Comment: @blog: Why can't you rename the column?